# How do I save web apps to use offline?

Tags: offline

I want to be able to use web apps (like http://www.epochconverter.com/, or any other, really) *offline*. How do I save them? ("Save as…" doesn't work).

Comment: By and large, web apps _can't_ be used offline. At least not without being built that way. For those that can, each will have implemented it in a slightly different way. So your question is really too broad; if you have a question about how to do this with _a specific app_, that would probably be fine.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is a program called [HTTrack](https://www.httrack.com/).  It takes a URL and downloads all of the client files it can find, building a full copy of the site, including subpages and javascript.

The browser "Save File" feature will download a very basic version of a site.  Much of the site will use references to things that are on the internet.  This will only work if it's a very simple site with most of the scripting built into the HTML.

This will not work for all web apps.  Some apps communicate with the server to perform calculations or load new content.  For example, you will never be able to save Pandora to your hard drive, because it needs its server connection to load new songs.